# CreateUserWizard - Change position of the validation message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider

I am using a CreateUserWizard.

- By default, the validation error messages are shown in the bottom of the control. Can I change this positioning to be shown above the control so that it is consistent with my other pages?
- When a user fails to enter a required fied, it displays a asterisk * next to the field. Can I have it also display some text saying that the field is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ContentTemplate to control where elements are displayed, including the validation message. This [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.aspx) steps you through it. Not sure about the asterisk, though.

Comment: I am using the CSS friendy adapters http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/membership/CreateUserWizard.aspx

Can I still use the ContentTemplate

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with those adapters. Not sure.